# Pausing script execution until user quits out of `less`

Tags: shell-script, less, control-flow

**Goal**: `less` the contents (from a variable) and then ask the user whether the contents should be saved to a file (i.e., `.recovered_object`) *only after* the user quits out of `less`.

The excerpt from my script is reproduced below:

```bsh
...
    # Show each blob until one is chosen
    counter=1
    while IFS='' read sha; do
        printf "Showing blob %d of %d" "$counter" "$BLOB_COUNT"
        contents=$(git show ${sha})
        ${PAGER:-less} ${contents}
        if read -q '?Save and quit (y/n) ?'; then
            echo "$contents" > .recovered_object
            exit 0
        else
            ((counter++))
        fi
    done <<< ${DANGLING_BLOBS_SHA}

    exit 0
```

As it stands now, any keypress (other than `y`) skips to the next file...but this precludes the user from scrolling up (`k`) or down (`j`) or using `less`'s other keymappings!

How do I prevent the `if` block from immediately running?

---

PS: I'm pretty new to shell scripting in general, so any pointers are welcome.

PSS: I am using `zsh`, but am not opposed to switching to `bash` if that's more conducive to achieving the desired UX.

Comment: I see a number of problems here: `less` expects a *filename* as an argument, not a bunch of data (also, the variable isn't quoted, so it'll go through word splitting and wildcard expansion anyway). Since input to the loop is redirected (with `<<<`), `read` is going to read from that instead of the terminal. Also, `echo ... > .recovered_object` will overwrite any previous contents, so you'll only get the *last* saved blob (the previous ones have been overwritten).

Comment: For my purposes, I want to keep the here-string and I only want the latest chosen contents saved to `.recovered_object`. Thanks for catching the quotation issue.

Answer (score 0):

Using process substitution with the `-f` flag (also `--force`) seemed to work:

`${PAGER:-less} -f <(echo "$contents")`

Comment: Why not just `echo "$contents" | "${PAGER:-less}"`, instead of relying on a `less`-specific `-f`?

Comment: Ooof. Yes, that's far more sensible. Thanks.